# Swift: How can we extract a subview from xib in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode editor, just like we have **Editor > Embed In** , Do we have anything like this to extract a subview from views hierarchy to a new xib file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy it with `⌘ + c` and paste it anywhere inside the other xib , or you can duplicate the entire xib with `⇧ + ⌘ + s` then write a new name